# command request me to report it's bug?

Tags: bug-reporting

Today I got a message when I was using *ld* command .

It says :

**ld: Please report this bug.**

So, What should I do ?

Is it serious or just I should ignore it?

(if it is good to report it, I'll learn to do that ;) no Problem )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to File the Bug report follow this

[How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

You may consider reinstalling that package . Every bug get the affinity of being **Serious , Low Urgency , etc**.  as per concluded by the Development team. But you need to report the bug for that.

It is a **good practice** , since you are **Contributing to Ubuntu Development** by reporting a bug . It helps in **fixing** it which get ends up in Updates as newer version with **bug fixes and other features** , thereby making your system more Secure and Robust.

Comment: Reinstalling 'ld' ... why ? That was interesting that it itself said that a bug is happened!

Comment: Just to make sure that it is a bug , if  a bug then it will definitely give the same output , just a self-confirmation step :D ,which is why is said that you **MAY** :) , otherwise there is absolutely no problem.